# Equivalent properties for a locally compact space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this exercise:

> Let  $(E,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space; prove that the following are
>   equivalent:
>
> 1) $(E,\tau)$ is locally compact.
>
> 2) For all $x\in E$ and $U\in \mathcal{V}_x$ an open neighborhood,
>   there exists a relatively compact open set $K$ such that $x\in K\subset
> \overline{K}\subset U$
>
> 3) For all compact $K$ and all open $U$ with $K\subset U$,
>    there exists $A$ relatively compact and open  such that $K\subset A\subset
> \overline{A}\subset U$

In order to prove that  1) implies 2) I say:

Let $x\in E$ and $U\in \mathcal{V}_x$ as $E$ is locally compact then $x$ has a compact neighbohood $W\in \mathcal{V}_x$, $W$ is a neighborhood of  $x$ so there exist an open set $U'$ such that $x\in U'\subset W$

After that i don't know how to continue, how can i find the $K$ relatively compact ?

and for $2)\Rightarrow 3)$ and $3)\Rightarrow 1)$ I have no idea

Can you help me please

Thank you.

Comment: I left in my answer the discussion about the original formulation. Please, remove all obsolete comments.

Comment: i don't understande what i must do ? i corrected my message

Comment: Just click on the ⌘ button that appears next to comment when you hover on them. Those comments are now useless, since you edited the question.

Comment: @egreg  can you see this for me and expalain me the given answer please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181254/weak-and-strong-convergence

Comment: Sorry, but that's too much into functional analysis; I remember general topology because I used it quite extensively, but functional analysis was just an exam and I have forgotten most part of it since.

Comment: ok no problem  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The proof

(1)$\implies$(2) Since $X$ is locally compact, there is a compact neighborhood $W$ of $x$. Consider $V$, the interior of $W\cap U$, which is an open set containing $x$.

Since $V\subseteq W$, $V$ is open in the relative topology of $W$. Therefore $W\setminus V$ is closed in $W$, hence compact. For each point $y\in W\setminus V$, choose an open neighborhood $N(y)$ of $y$ (in the space $W$) which doesn't contain $x$. This is possible because $X$ is Hausdorff. Since the sets $N(y)$ cover $W\setminus V$, we can find an open subcover, say 
$$W\setminus V\subset N(y_1)\cup\dots\cup N(y_m).$$
Then $V\supset A=(W\setminus N(y_1))\cap(W\setminus N(y_k))$ which is a closed set in $W$, so it is compact, hence closed in $V$. Moreover $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $V$, so also a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Take as $K$ the interior of $A$, which ends the proof.

(2)$\implies$(3) For each $x\in K$, condition 2 provides us a relatively compact open set $K(x)$ such that $x\in K(x)\subset \overline{K(x)}\subset U$. Since $K$ is compact, we have $K\subset A=K(x_1)\cup\subset\cup K(x_m)$. Then $\overline{A}=\overline{K(x_1)}\cup\dots\cup\overline{K(x_m}$ which is compact and included in $U$.

(3)$\implies$(1) Let $x\in E$. Then condition 3 applied to $K=\{x\}$ and $U=E$ provides us with a relatively compact open set $A$ such that $x\in A$. Then $\overline{A}$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$.

---

<sub>Note: this part of the answer is about the original formulation of the question.</sub>

The statement, in its original formulation (where the “$K$ open” and “$A$ open” clauses were missing from conditions 2 and 3), is false. Condition 2 would be satisfied by every Hausdorff space: just take $K=\{x\}$. Similarly for condition 3: just take $A=K$.

Comment: allways if $W$ is compact then $W\setminus V$ is compact ? thank you ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Since $V$ is open in $W$, $W\setminus V$ is closed in $W$, so compact.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x$ you have proved the existence of an open set $U'$ (you called it $U'$) that is contained in a compact set $W$. This $U'$ is relatively compact since $\bar U'\subset W$.

Now to prove 2), take any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and let $K=U\cap U'$. Then $\bar K$ is a closed set contained in $W$, so $K$ is relatively compact.

Comment: Ohhh so my $K$ is juste $U'$ !!

Comment: What do you mean by prove 2) ?

Comment: have you an idea about how to prove that $2)\Rightarrow 3)$ and $3)\Rightarrow 1)$

Comment: WHY $\overline{K}\subset U$ ????????