# Weak and strong convergence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I have  the sequence $(v_n)\subset H^1_0(0,1)$ such that $v_n\rightharpoonup v $ (weakly) in $H^1_0(0,1)$ and $v_n\rightarrow v$ in $L^2(0,1)$ and $v_n\rightarrow v$ in $C^0(0,1)$

My question is why $$\int_0^1 v_n(x) (v_n(x)-v(x)) dx\rightarrow 0$$

I say that $\int_0^1 v_n (v_n-v) dx=\int_0^1 (v_n-v+v)(v_n-v) dx= \int_0^1 (v_n-v)^2 dx +\int_0^1 v(v_n-v) dx=$
$ ||v_n-v||^2_{L^2(0,1)} +\int_0^1 v(v_n-v) dx$

By the fact that $v_n\rightarrow v$ in $L^2(0,1)$ we have that $||v_n-v||_{L^2}\rightarrow 0.$

But why $\int_0^1 v(v_n-v) dx\rightarrow 0$ ???

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from an application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Indeed, 
$$\left|\int_0^1 v(x)(v_n(x)-v(x))\mathrm dx\right|^2\leqslant \int_0^1v(x)^2\mathrm dx\cdot \int_0^1\left(v_n(x)-v(x)\right)^2\mathrm dx=\int_0^1v(x)^2\mathrm dx\cdot\lVert v_n-v\rVert_2.$$

Comment: Or, in other words, the stong convergence in $L^2$ imply the weak convergence in $L^2$

Comment: $\int_0^1 v(v_n-v) dx\leq ||v||_{L^2}^2+||v_n-v||^2 \rightarrow ||v||_{L^2}^2 $ not $0$ no ?

Comment: @Tryss or Davide Giraudo , can you help me ?

Comment: @Tryss can you explain me more please ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou See edit.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh sorry i must do $\times$ i do $+$ i'am a big zero thank you @DavideGiraudo